# Python console: ImportError PyUnicodeUCS4_FromString

Tags: python-3.x, importerror, undefined-symbol

Can anyone help me to figure out what is happening and how to solve this error?

The following message happens when I try to import a module I compiled before:

```
Python 3.1.4 (default, Mar  8 2012, 09:13:26)
[GCC 4.3.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pypt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.1/site-packages/pypt.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_FromString
```

Comment: You are probably running the compiled module with a different interpreter than the one you compiled the module with. Python can be built with an internal Unicode representation of UCS2 or UCS4. Do you have more than one Python installation?

Comment: I read something about it as well. Yes, on _/usr/local/lib/_ I have python2.5, 2.6, 3.1 and 3.2. I used **python3.1** for compilation and interpretation, I guess.

Comment: Where is the source for this `pypt` module available? I can't find anything obvious on _PyPI_ .

Comment: I had a wrong path for the library, on my make file, corrected it but didn't sold the problem at all. I'm not sure if I understood you, `pypt` is a module created by me and it's in the same directory as make file. After the libpath correction the only thing different was: `./pypt.so`

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was a third party module. Are you using `setuptools` or `distutils` to do the compilation? Have you tried creating a [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html) and doing the compilation with it activated?

Comment: I'm using `distutils`. And I finally find the problem, it seams that **python3** = _/usr/local/lib/python3_ (v 3.1.4) and I was compiling with version 3.1.3 which was located _/usr/bin/python3_.
So, you're right with your first comment. Thank you so much for your help!!