# Import Error when trying to use TensorFlow

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, pip, importerror, undefined-symbol

I am fairly new to TensorFlow and just installed it with CPU-support-only version following to this: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux
My Ubuntu is 16.04 and python installed is 2.7.13. I chose "native" pip installation.

The download and install process went though smoothly, however, when I tried to import Tensorflow and use it, it returns following error;

```
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_FromString
```

I have got no clue how to solve it after crawling in google. 
If you know some idea on how to solve this and could give me some advice, much appreciated.
Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: I haven't seen this particular error before with TensorFlow, but there is a general Python issue that's mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12805044/python-console-importerror-pyunicodeucs4-fromstring that may be related (though unfortunately there's no good solution there).

Answer (score 2):

It's because your python is built with UCS2, which is incompatible with the one assumed by tensorflow (UCS4). So either you build your python with UCS4 (--enable-unicode=ucs4) or build tensorflow from source may solve this issue, I guess.